# How to trigger a google map resize when a jQuery event runs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, google-maps

I'm creating a store loacator for a site using the Map List Pro plugin displaying inside a popup created using the Popup Maker plugin.

version in progress: https://beastsofbalance.com/pop-test-page/ - click the 'store locator' link to open it

When the pop-up is opened, the Google map doesn't load.

The documentation for the Map List Pro plugin suggests this is because it's initially hidden on page load: http://www.maplistpro.com/documentation/only-part-of-the-map-shows-the-rest-is-grey/

it gives two code snippets to solve the issue, but says the pop-up plugin will have a custom event I need to add this to.

The two snippets are: 
`google.maps.event.trigger(MapListProMaps[0].map, "resize");` - for an individual map

`$(document).trigger({type: "resizeMap"});` - for all maps

The documentation for the Popup Maker plugin says the event pumAfterOpen runs just after the pop-up has opened:
http://docs.wppopupmaker.com/article/42-popup-maker-jquery-api

I don't have enough (any!) jQuery / javascript knowledge to put these two bits of information together to create a working code snippet which will trigger a reload of the map when the pop-up is opened, and I was very much hoping someone might be able to help me out!

Many thanks

Hannah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried the following on a copy of your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery(document).on('pumAfterOpen',function(e){
        jQuery(document).trigger({type: "resizeMap"});
    });
});
```

I can't see the map resizing because of authorisation issues with the Google API, but it should be enough to get you on the right track.

Comment: Mike you're a hero, this has worked perfectly - thanks so much! :D